# Do I need to gamma correct the final color output on a modern computer/monitor

Tags: opengl, graphics, rendering, gamma

I've been under the assumption that my gamma correction pipeline should be as follows:

- Use sRGB format for all textures loaded in (`GL_SRGB8_ALPHA8`) as all art programs pre-gamma correct their files. When sampling from a `GL_SRGB8_ALPHA8` texture in a shader OpenGL will automatically convert to linear space.
- Do all lighting calculations, post processing, etc. in linear space.
- Convert back to sRGB space when writing final color that will be displayed on the screen.

Note that in my case the final color write involves me writing from a FBO (which is a linear RGB texture) to the back buffer.

My assumption has been challenged as if I gamma correct in the final stage my colors are brighter than they should be. I set up for a solid color to be drawn by my lights of value { 255, **106**, 0 }, but when I render I get { 255, **171**, 0 } (as determined by print-screening and color picking). Instead of orange I get yellow. If I **don't** gamma correct at the final step I get exactly the right value of { 255, **106**, 0 }.

According to [some resources](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Illumination/Tut12%20Monitors%20and%20Gamma.html#d0e12272) modern LCD screens mimic CRT gamma. Do they always? If not, how can I tell if I should gamma correct? Am I going wrong somewhere else?

---

### Edit 1

I've now noticed that even though the color I write with the light is correct, places where I use colors from textures are not correct (but rather far darker as I would expect without gamma correction). I don't know where this disparity is coming from.

---

### Edit 2

After trying `GL_RGBA8` for my textures instead of `GL_SRGB8_ALPHA8`, everything looks perfect, even when using the texture values in lighting computations (if I half the intensity of the light, the output color values are halfed).

My code is no longer taking gamma correction into account anywhere, and my output looks correct.

This confuses me even more, is gamma correction no longer needed/used?

---

### Edit 3 - In response to [datenwolf's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23030225/2507444)

After some more experimenting I'm confused on a couple points here.

**1 - Most image formats are stored non-linearly (in sRGB space)**

I've loaded a few images (in my case both .png and .bmp images) and examined the raw binary data. It appears to me as though the images are actually in the **RGB** color space, as if I compare the values of pixels with an image editing program with the byte array I get in my program they match up perfectly. Since my image editor is giving me RGB values, this would indicate the image stored in RGB.

I'm using stb_image.h/.c to load my images and followed it all the way through loading a .png and did not see anywhere that it gamma corrected the image while loading. I also examined the .bmps in a hex editor and the values on disk matched up for them.

If these images are actually stored on disk in linear RGB space, how am I supposed to (programatically) know when to specify an image is in sRGB space? Is there some way to query for this that a more featured image loader might provide? Or is it up to the image creators to save their image as gamma corrected (or not) - meaning establishing a convention and following it for a given project. I've asked a couple artists and neither of them knew what gamma correction is.

If I specify my images are sRGB, they are too dark unless I gamma correct in the end (which would be understandable if the monitor output using sRGB, but see point #2).

**2 - "On most computers the effective scanout LUT is linear! What does this mean though?"**

I'm not sure I can find where this thought is finished in your response.

From what I can tell, having experimented, all monitors I've tested on output linear values. If I draw a full screen quad and color it with a hard-coded value in a shader with **no** gamma correction the monitor displays the correct value that I specified.

What the sentence I quoted above from your answer and my results would lead me to believe is that **modern monitors output linear values (i.e. do not emulate CRT gamma)**.

The target platform for our application is the PC. For this platform (excluding people with CRTs or really old monitors), would it be reasonable to do whatever your response to #1 is, then for #2 to **not** gamma correct (i.e. not perform the final RGB->sRGB transformation - either manually or using GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB)?

If this is so, what are the platforms on which GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB is meant for (or where it would be valid to use it today), or are monitors that use linear RGB really that new (given that GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB was introduced 2008)?

--

I've talked to a few other graphics devs at my school and from the sounds of it, none of them have taken gamma correction into account and they have not noticed anything incorrect (some were not even aware of it). One dev in particular said that he got incorrect results when taking gamma into account so he then decided to not worry about gamma. **I'm unsure what to do in my project for my target platform given the conflicting information I'm getting online/seeing with my project.**

---

### Edit 4 - In response to [datenwolf's updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23030225/2507444)

> Yes, indeed. If somewhere in the signal chain a nonlinear transform is applied, but all the pixel values go unmodified from the image to the display, then that nonlinearity has already been pre-applied on the image's pixel values. Which means, that the image is already in a nonlinear color space.

Your response would make sense to me if I was examining the image on my display. To be sure I was clear, when I said I was examining the byte array for the image I mean I was examining the numerical value in memory for the texture, not the image output on the screen (which I **did** do for point #2). To me the only way I could see what you're saying to be true then is if the image editor was giving me values in sRGB space.

Also note that I did try examining the output on monitor, as well as **modifying** the texture color (for example, dividing by half or doubling it) and the output appeared correct (measured using the method I describe below).

> How did you measure the signal response?

Unfortunately my methods of measurement are far cruder than yours. When I said I experimented on my monitors what I meant was that I output solid color full screen quad whose color was hard coded in a shader to a plain OpenGL framebuffer (which does not do any color space conversion when written to). When I output white, 75% gray, 50% gray, 25% gray and black the correct colors are displayed. Now here my interpretation of correct colors could most certainly be wrong. I take a screenshot and then use an image editing program to see what the values of the pixels are (as well as a visual appraisal to make sure the values make sense). If I understand correctly, if my monitors were non-linear I would need to perform a RGB->sRGB transformation before presenting them to the display device for them to be correct.

I'm not going to lie, I feel I'm getting a bit out of my depth here. I'm thinking the solution I might persue for my second point of confusion (the final RGB->sRGB transformation) will be a tweakable brightness setting and default it to what looks correct on my devices (no gamma correction).

Comment: @NicolBolas wrote an excellent tutorial on the subject: http://arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Texturing/Tutorial%2016.html And that's not even exhaustive

Comment: @datenwolf I linked to that as "some resources" above. I've read it but the results I'm getting seem to be the opposite of what the tutorial indicates - unless I'm misunderstanding it.

Comment: I took this opportunity to further my writings about OpenGL and matching color spaces. I'll post an excerptive answer later.

Comment: Okay, my answer is up. It's a bit lengthy though.

Comment: @PeterClark dear Peter, i am wondering if after the long discussion you have finally found out the answer to your problem. because I am facing a similar problem: I take a bmp image, i check that it is in sRGB format which means gamma corrected with `gamma = 1/2.2`, then in order to make grayscale I apply inverse correction to all color channels with `gamma=2.2`, then use linear transform 'gray = 0.2126 * r + 0.7152 * g + 0.0722 * b' and then transform the gray color with `gamma = 1/2.2` before saving to bmp. surprisingly, without gamma-correction i get a better grayscale image...

Comment: @JohnSmith Apologies for the long delayed response! My final conclusion walking away from this was that for my use case (a game) it's best to implement a gamma slider to let users adjust as needed. That ended up being a good enough solution for me and I haven't had to revisit it since. I tested on several machines with various graphics cards and monitors (which all had the same behavior which I've since forgotten) and tweaked the default setting to look good on these machines.

Comment: @PeterClark thanks for answering. may be a good solution for you, when you care only about the visual perception. but I am personally still puzzled if the gamma correction is always present in sRGB images, since I need to work with linear intensities. and some articles, which are supposed to explain gamma correction, puzzle me even more. for example, this one http://blog.johnnovak.net/2016/09/21/what-every-coder-should-know-about-gamma/ where the author says, that fig.2 looks more evenly spaced than fig.1. well, on my monitor fir.1 looks much better in darker region. sigh...

Comment: @JohnSmith I just want to verify - what do you mean by "looks much better in the darker region" in regards to figure 1 vs figure 2. On my monitor figure 2 has a far larger range of dark colors than figure 1. For me figure 1 gets lighter far faster than it's supposed to -  by the half way point of the bar it's already way past 0.5% brightness by my eyes. Does this image not match what you're seeing: https://imgur.com/a/OPqQy ?

Comment: @datenwolf Looks like the conclusion is we still need gamma-corrected signals to be fed to displays (CRTs and LCDs alike) as saying ["gamma exists for legacy reasons" is false](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/107969/88300). Related reading: [Rehabilitation of Gamma](https://poynton.ca/PDFs/Rehabilitation_of_gamma.pdf). Also [outputting in sRGB implicitly means gamma-corrected](https://alfonse.bitbucket.io/oldtut/Texturing/Tut16%20Free%20Gamma%20Correction.html).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

First of all you must understand that the nonlinear mapping applied to the color channels is often more than just a simple power function. sRGB nonlinearity can be approximated by about x^2.4, but that's not really the real deal. Anyway your primary assumptions are more or less correct.

If your textures are stored in the more common image file formats, they will contain the values as they are presented to the graphics scanout. Now there are two common hardware scenarios:

- The scanout interface outputs a linear signal and the display device will then internally apply a nonlinear mapping. Old CRT monitors were nonlinear due to their physics: The amplifiers could put only so much current into the electron beam, the phosphor saturating and so on – that's why the whole gamma thing was introduced in the first place, to model the nonlinearities of CRT displays.
- Modern LCD and OLED displays either use resistor ladders in their driver amplifiers, or they have gamma ramp lookup tables in their image processors.
- Some devices however are linear, and ask the image producing device to supply a proper matching LUT for the desired output color profile on the scanout.

*On most computers the effective scanout LUT is linear!* What does this mean though? A little detour:

---

For illustration I quickly hooked up my laptop's analogue display output (VGA connector) to my analogue oscilloscope: Blue channel onto scope channel 1, green channel to scope channel 2, external triggering on line synchronization signal (HSync). A quick and dirty OpenGL program, deliberately written with immediate mode was used to generate a linear color ramp:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

void display()
{
    GLuint win_width = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH);
    GLuint win_height = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT);

    glViewport(0,0, win_width, win_height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, 1, 0, 1, -1, 1);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glBegin(GL_QUAD_STRIP);
        glColor3f(0., 0., 0.);
        glVertex2f(0., 0.);
        glVertex2f(0., 1.);
        glColor3f(1., 1., 1.);
        glVertex2f(1., 0.);
        glVertex2f(1., 1.);
    glEnd();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE);
    
    glutCreateWindow("linear");
    glutFullScreen();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);

    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

The graphics output was configured with the Modeline

```
"1440x900_60.00"  106.50  1440 1528 1672 1904  900 903 909 934 -HSync +VSync
```

(because that's the same mode the flat panel runs in, and I was using cloning mode)

- gamma=2 LUT on the green channel.
- linear (gamma=1) LUT on the blue channel

This is how the signals of a single scanout line look like (upper curve: Ch2 = green, lower curve: Ch1 = blue):

[image: Analogue Video Signals Gamma=1 and Gamma=2]

You can clearly see the x⟼x² and x⟼x mappings (parabola and linear shapes of the curves).

---

Now after this little detour we know, that the pixel values that go to the main framebuffer, go there as they are: The OpenGL linear ramp underwent no further changes and only when a nonlinear scanout LUT was applied it altered the signal sent to the display.

Either way the values you present to the scanout (which means the on-screen framebuffers) will undergo a nonlinear mapping at some point in the signal chain. And for all standard consumer devices this mapping will be according to the sRGB standard, because it's the smallest common factor (i.e. images represented in the sRGB color space can be reproduced on most output devices).

Since most programs, like webbrowsers assume the output to undergo a sRGB to display color space mapping, they simply copy the pixel values of the standard image file formats to the on-screen frame as they are, without performing a color space conversion, thereby implying that the color values within those images are in sRGB color space (or they will often merely convert to sRGB, if the image color profile is not sRGB); the correct thing to do (if, and only if the color values written to the framebuffer are scanned out to the display unaltered; assuming that scanout LUT is part of the display), would be conversion to the specified color profile the display expects.

But this implies, that the on-screen framebuffer itself is in sRGB color space (I don't want to split hairs about how idiotic that is, lets just accept this fact).

How to bring this together with OpenGL? First of all, OpenGL does all it's color operations linearly. However since the scanout is expected to be in some nonlinear color space, this means, that the end result of the rendering operations of OpenGL somehow must be brougt into the on-screen framebuffer color space.

This is where the [`ARB_framebuffer_sRGB`](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/framebuffer_sRGB.txt) extension (which went core with OpenGL-3) enters the picture, which introduced new flags used for the configuration of window pixelformats:

```
New Tokens

    Accepted by the <attribList> parameter of glXChooseVisual, and by
    the <attrib> parameter of glXGetConfig:

        GLX_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB_CAPABLE_ARB             0x20B2

    Accepted by the <piAttributes> parameter of
    wglGetPixelFormatAttribivEXT, wglGetPixelFormatAttribfvEXT, and
    the <piAttribIList> and <pfAttribIList> of wglChoosePixelFormatEXT:

        WGL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB_CAPABLE_ARB             0x20A9

    Accepted by the <cap> parameter of Enable, Disable, and IsEnabled,
    and by the <pname> parameter of GetBooleanv, GetIntegerv, GetFloatv,
    and GetDoublev:

        FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB                             0x8DB9
```

So if you have a window configured with such a sRGB pixelformat **and** enable sRGB rasterization mode in OpenGL with `glEnable(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB);` the result of the linear colorspace rendering operations will be transformed in sRGB color space.

Another way would be to render everything into an off-screen FBO and to the color conversion in a postprocessing shader.

But that's only the output side of rendering signal chain. You also got input signals, in the form of textures. And those are usually images, with their pixel values stored nonlinearly. So before those can be used in linear image operations, such images must be brought into a linear color space first. Lets just ignore for the time being, that mapping nonlinear color spaces into linear color spaces opens several of cans of worms upon itself – which is why the sRGB color space is so ridiculously small, namely to avoid those problems.

So to address this an extension [`EXT_texture_sRGB`](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/texture_sRGB.txt) was introduced, which turned out to be so vital, that it never went through being ARB, but went straight into the OpenGL specification itself: Behold the `GL_SRGB…` internal texture formats.

A texture loaded with this format undergoes a sRGB to linear RGB colorspace transformation, before being used to source samples. This gives linear pixel values, suitable for linear rendering operations, and the result can then be validly transformed to sRGB when going to the main on-screen framebuffer.

---

---

A personal note on the whole issue: Presenting images on the on-screen framebuffer in the target device color space IMHO is a huge design flaw. There's no way to do everything right in such a setup without going insane.

What one really wants is to have the on-screen framebuffer in a linear, contact color space; the natural choice would be CIEXYZ. Rendering operations would naturally take place in the same contact color space. Doing all graphics operations in contact color spaces, avoids the opening of the aforementioned cans-of-worms involved with trying to push a square peg named linear RGB through a nonlinear, round hole named sRGB.

And although I don't like the design of Weston/Wayland very much, at least it offers the opportunity to actually implement such a display system, by having the clients render and the compositor operate in contact color space and apply the output device's color profiles in a last postprocessing step.

The only drawback of contact color spaces is, that there it's imperative to use deep color (i.e. > 12 bits per color channel). In fact 8 bits are completely insufficient, even with nonlinear RGB (the nonlinearity helps a bit to cover up the lack of perceptible resolution).

---

## Update

> I've loaded a few images (in my case both .png and .bmp images) and examined the raw binary data. It appears to me as though the images are actually in the RGB color space, as if I compare the values of pixels with an image editing program with the byte array I get in my program they match up perfectly. Since my image editor is giving me RGB values, this would indicate the image stored in RGB.

Yes, indeed. If somewhere in the signal chain a nonlinear transform is applied, but all the pixel values go unmodified from the image to the display, then that nonlinearity has already been pre-applied on the image's pixel values. Which means, that the image is already in a nonlinear color space.

> > **2 - "On most computers the effective scanout LUT is linear! What does this mean though?**
>
> I'm not sure I can find where this thought is finished in your response.

This thought is elaborated in the section that immediately follows, where I show how the values you put into a plain (OpenGL) framebuffer go directly to the monitor, unmodified. The idea of sRGB is "put the values into the images exactly as they are sent to the monitor and build consumer displays to follow that sRGB color space".

> From what I can tell, having experimented, all monitors I've tested on output linear values.

How did you measure the signal response? Did you use a calibrated power meter or similar device to measure the light intensity emitted from the monitor in response to the signal? You can't trust your eyes with that, because like all our senses our eyes have a logarithmic signal response.

---

## Update 2

> To me the only way I could see what you're saying to be true then is if the image editor was giving me values in sRGB space.

That's indeed the case. Because color management was added to all the widespread graphics systems as an afterthought, most image editors edit pixel values in their destination color space. Note that one particular design parameter of sRGB was, that it should merely retroactively specify the unmanaged, direct value transfer color operations as they were (and mostly still are done) done on consumer devices. Since there happens no color management at all, the values contained in the images and manipulated in editors must be in sRGB already. This works for so long, as long images are not synthetically created in a linear rendering process; in case of the later the render system has to take into account the destination color space.

> I take a screenshot and then use an image editing program to see what the values of the pixels are

Which gives you of course only the raw values in the scanout buffer *without* the gamma LUT and the display nonlinearity applied.

Comment: Awesome answer, it does answer my main question but also brings up a few more questions for me. I'll accept the answer now, but will try to formulate (and hopefully answer) my other questions over the next week. Would the best SO practice be to edit my question here with my findings, or ask (and answer if I can) new questions?

Comment: @PeterClark: If the new questions are refinements of your original question, edit them into the question. If they create a new topic, better ask a different question and cross reference them.

Comment: I've updated my question with my points of confusion. I apologize for taking so long.

Comment: I've edited my question with a response to your update. Thanks again for taking the time to help.

Comment: I think that update 2 gives me enough to work with and correct our color pipeline, thanks a ton for the clarifications!

Comment: the insanity is there for sure. but it exists because of 8 bits quantization reasons. since our eyes are logarithmic, using power(2.2)  in the screen makes a linear ramp in the quantization appears linear to our eyes. this is very good for bit entropy uniformity. If we were to use linear storage everywhere, we would need 10 bits per channel. so just take the insanity, or ask everybody to throw bits away. that's going to be a SERIOUS industry shift. all image formats store 8 bits per channel, except HDR formats. (exr, rgbe..)

Comment: @v.oddou: Most OpenGL implementations support bit depth formats just fine. And that's all what this question and discussion is about. BTW: You cannot do image operations properly if you have nonlinearities applied (interesting enough many image processing programs, including the very expensive ones get this wrong, see http://www.4p8.com/eric.brasseur/gamma.html for details). When it comes to on-screen formats there'a also wide support for R10_G10_B10_A2. A few months ago I had an exchange about this on the Wayland-Devel maillist.

Comment: @v.oddou: Also the gamma 2.2 has nothing to do with the nonlinearity of our eyes, but that's not the true reason for gamma. The gamma factor is in fact due to the nonlinearity of the first display devices, namely CRTs, where the electron beam current vs. signal voltage has a nonlinear relationship. CRTs then were calibrated for a gamma factor of 2.2 and that's what we still have today. Also display systems designed in the 21st century use different gamma values, e.g. 2.6 for Digital Cinema.

Comment: @datenwolf: actually I take back the 10 bits. this resource shows it : http://www.4p8.com/eric.brasseur/gamma.html linear space value 1 would still need to get 20 shades before it, so it means 4 or 5 bits would be needed, therefore 12 or 13 bits per channel. and for SDR. this is just bad quantization. just stick to gamma storage and the world and little children will be better off.

Comment: @v.oddou: Yes, gamma-encoded **storage** is just fine. But nobody is talking about storage in this Q&A and discussion. We're talking about **image processing** here. The most widely supported OpenGL deep color formats are 16 bit per channel.

Comment: yes, 16 bits of half float. the half float is itself antiexponential in its precision, but its over-quantized so we can suppose its ok. processing should be done in linear space and high bit depth. I think everybody agrees on that. But its important to keep quantization issues in mind, because we cannot state "we should do all linear everywhere all the time and things would be simple".

Comment: @v.oddou: No, not half float. Integer. 16 bits of integer. Floating point formats must be explicitly requested. And yes, you get the full 16 bits of precision, because some graphics algorithms depend on them being available. OpenGL-3.0 (and later) explicitly specify for 16 bit integer formats being available (see section 3.9, p. 180 ff of the GL-3.0 spec).

Comment: Thanks a lot for debunking this "everything-is-linear" crap with your oscillator! Ubercool! It seems a herculean task to get people to accept the simple physical facts in video.

Comment: Great answer, though I'd like to mention that sRGB encoding is an "equivalent" simplified gamma of 1/2.2 not 1/2.4 — 2.4 is used as part of the "correct" TRC encode, but with the linearized toe the *effective* curve is about 2.2

Comment: Also in response to a comment above, gamma is very much employed due to our human non-linear perception. True that the electrostatic interaction of electron gun and cathode in a CRT is non-linear as designed, it was used in broadcast television intentionally as it substantially reduced the perception of noise (perceptually a 30dB noise reduction, see Wilkenson). CRT gamma could have been designed "out" but it is beneficial.  The same is true in digital — gamma encoding (aka pre-emphasis( allows fewer bits for an equivalent image fidelity. 8 bit per channel needs gamma!

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to give a simple explanation of what went wrong in the initial attempt, because although the accepted answer goes in-depth on colorspace theory, it doesn't really answer that.

The setup of the pipeline was exactly right: use `GL_SRGB8_ALPHA8` for textures, `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB` (or custom shader code) to convert back to sRGB at the end, and all your intermediate calculations will be using linear light.

The last bit is where you ran into trouble. You wanted a light with a color of (255, 106, 0) - **but that's an sRGB color, and you're working with linear light.** To get the color you want, you need to convert that color to the linear space, the same way that `GL_SRGB8_ALPHA8` is doing for your textures. For your case, this would be a vec3 light with intensity (1, .1441, 0) - this is the value after applying gamma-compression.