# Programmatically Adjusting Monitor Color

Tags: graphics, colors, vga

I want to create a simple slider that will adjust one of the colors in my monitor at a hardware level.  I want to do this to adjust a color to the exact way an eye sees it. I know a profiler will get most of the work done but I'm concerned with the other 10% that's just not quite right and could be adjusted manually. I'm not really sure how this whole display thing works. Can someone point me in a direction to start my research?

So far the hurdles I see are making it work the same on all graphics cards and/or trying to double profile the display if there is another color profiler running in the background. I would like to be able to write one program that would work on any computer. Is this even practical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to create a simple slider that will adjust one of the colors in my monitor at a hardware level.

I think you've been unsucessfull because you don't know yourself, what you actually want to do. "One of the colors" is sooo unspecific.

Do you mean, that you want to change a very specific pixel value on the whole of the screen?(can be done effectively only if you replace the system's compositor, and works only if graphics is composited).

Or do you mean to adjust the ramp for one of the primary channels of your display? In that case you should look for "gamma LUT API". Googling " Gamma Curve API" will deliver results.

Windows: [SetDeviceGammaRamp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd372194%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

X11: Use the XRandR extension to set the LUT. http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/proto/randrproto/plain/randrproto.txt

> Should I be researching VGA, sVGA, OpenGL?

Neither of them deals with this.

Comment: Yes I do mean change a very specific value on the screen. I have edited my post to be more specific.

Comment: @shakabra: Adjusting one single value is not going to help you a lot, worst case it creats severe banding. Proper color calibration has to cover the whole range of tristimuli going through the graphics stack. And a profiler does an extremely good job doing that. Using a manual adjustment will just make things look worse again. Also it may be, that the color you're aiming for is *impossible* to show, because it lies outside of the gamut of your particular display device. It may not help you a lot, but I think this is a read worth your while anyway: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23030225/524368

Comment: Thanks. I really was wondering whether or not this was practical. You've helped a lot.