# Affine transformation in linear RGB space

Tags: java, image-processing, graphics2d

If the source raster in [linear RGB color space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524623/what-are-the-practical-differences-when-working-with-colors-in-a-linear-vs-a-no) is transformed using the following Java code, the `java.awt.image.ImagingOpException: Unable to transform src image` error is thrown when the filter is applied (the last line).

```
ColorModel linearRGBColorModel = new DirectColorModel(
        ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_LINEAR_RGB), 32,
        0xff0000, 0xff00, 0xff, 0xff000000, true, DataBuffer.TYPE_INT);

WritableRaster srcRaster = linearRGBColorModel.createCompatibleWritableRaster(100, 100);
WritableRaster dstRaster = linearRGBColorModel.createCompatibleWritableRaster(200, 200);

BufferedImage srcImage = new BufferedImage(linearRGBColorModel, srcRaster, false, null);
BufferedImage dstImage = new BufferedImage(linearRGBColorModel, dstRaster, false, null);

AffineTransform aff = new AffineTransform();
aff.scale(2.0, 2.0);

AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(aff, null);
op.filter(srcImage, dstImage);
```

When `ColorSpace.CS_sRGB` is used instead, it works properly.

In real case I manipulate image with gray blurred line. Is transformation of such source just missing JDK feature or it doesn't make sense at all?

Anyway, I plan to recalculate pixels to sRGB and make the transformation afterwards.

Comment: What Java version and OS are you using? As `AffineTransformOp` uses native code under the hood, this may make a difference. I'm currently using Java 8 on Windows, and could reproduce your exception. Will try Java 7/8 on OS X later, when I'm reunited with my MBP. ;-)

Comment: @haraldK Tested on Windows 10 in Oracle JDK 8.

Comment: Same for OS X, Oracle Java 7, 8 and 9ea.

Answer (score 2):

Not really an explanation of why you code doesn't work*, but at least you can easily work around the issue. Instead of filtering the `BufferedImage`s:

```
op.filter(srcImage, dstImage);
```

...you could filter the `Raster`s:

```
op.filter(srcRaster, dstRaster);
```

Which will produce the same result (as using `filter(BufferedImage, BufferedImage)` on two images in sRGB color space).

As long as the color spaces and raster layouts are the same, the *type* of color space doesn't really matter.

---

*) I strongly believe this is a Java (JRE) bug, and should be reported to Oracle/OpenJDK.

Comment: I overlooked this option. Good to hear it has no side effects if both color spaces match.