# OpencvSharp LbgrtoLab

Tags: c#, opencv

Does anyone know what is "L" means in conversion code LbgrtoLab? I searched in web and cannot find any description on this conversion code, currently I tried to use both BgrtoLab / LbgrtoLab, I found that values are different in A and B channels with using same image source. Seems that LBgr can get a better result.

Currently I am using OpenCvSharp 2.4.10.

Answer (score 4):

Even though the meaning of this colour conversion code doesn't appear to be documented, there's no need to despair -- OpenCV is an open source library, so let's consult the [source code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.3.1/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp#L9761).

```
case COLOR_BGR2Lab: case COLOR_RGB2Lab: case COLOR_LBGR2Lab: case COLOR_LRGB2Lab:
case COLOR_BGR2Luv: case COLOR_RGB2Luv: case COLOR_LBGR2Luv: case COLOR_LRGB2Luv:

    // ....

    bool srgb = code == COLOR_BGR2Lab || code == COLOR_RGB2Lab
        || code == COLOR_RGB2Luv || code == COLOR_BGR2Luv;

    // ....

        if (srgb && usRGBGammaTab.empty())
            Mat(1, 256, CV_16UC1, sRGBGammaTab_b).copyTo(usRGBGammaTab);
        else if (ulinearGammaTab.empty())
            Mat(1, 256, CV_16UC1, linearGammaTab_b).copyTo(ulinearGammaTab);

    // ....
```

This suggests that the prefix `L` is meant to distinguish between non-linear (sRGB) and linear RGB colour spaces. More details about what this means can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12894053/3962537).